# Simple logic gate

Tags: digital-logic, diodes

Just a quick question on logic gates - in this case specifically on the diode. I've concluded for the following configurations of A and B (0,0 ; 0,1 ; 1,0) respectively \$V_{out}\$ returns 1, i.e. 5V because the circuit is open. Does the same apply for the case when both A and B have values 1 (meaning \$V_{out}\$ returns 1 too)?

[image: diagram]

I'm guessing it's the case since voltage in parallel circuits is the same and they do not sum up upon converging at the next branch.

Comment: Stuck the image inline for you. :)

Comment: If you label your components (e.g. D1, D2, D3, D4, R1) it will be easier to explain what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

Because of the two diodes at the inputs, neither A nor B can pull the output low.

Therefore the output is always high.

Assuming the load on Vout is high-impedance, only if A or B were above 6 V or so would they have any effect on the output voltage. In that case they could pull the output above 5 V.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]

One of these is OR logic and the other AND.
Your circuit is neither.